# Hard-wrap phpdoc

Tags: vim, phpdoc

I need a way to hard-wrap comments like phpdoc in vim (ideally, it would be better if javadoc and jsdoc could be wrapped the same way too, but right now I need phpdoc only). Are there any plugins providing a turnkey solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, my. Every single time I ask a stupid question, the solution is found right the same moment.

`gq` command does it not only for phpdoc, but for anything that has to be hard-wrapped. `:h gq` pretty much explains how it works.

Comment: Also see `:help auto-format` to do this automatically inside comments.